# Match values in two files and replace values in specific columns

Tags: awk

The purpose is to check if values for column 2 and 3 in file1 match with column 1 in file2. If any value match, then replace values in file2 for column 2 and 3 using the information of file1 columns 4 and 5.

**file1**

```
100,31431,37131,999991.70,2334362.30
100,31431,37471,111113.20,2334363.30
100,31433,36769,777775.60,2334361.90
102,31433,36853,333322.00,2334362.80
```

**file2**

```
3143137113 318512.50 2334387.50 100
3143137131 318737.50 2334387.50 100
3143137201 319612.50 2334387.50 100
3143137219 319837.50 2334387.50 100
3143137471 322987.50 2334387.50 100
3143137491 323237.50 2334387.50 100
3143336687 313187.50 2334412.50 100
3143336723 313637.50 2334412.50 100
3143336769 314212.50 2334412.50 100
3143336825 314912.50 2334412.50 100
3143336853 315262.50 2334412.50 102
```

**Output desired**

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,2334362.30,100
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37219,319837.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,2334363.30,100
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
31433,36687,313187.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36723,313637.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36769,777775.60,2334361.90,100
31433,36825,314912.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36853,333322.00,2334362.80,102
```

**I tried**

```
awk -F[, ] 'FNR==NR{a[$1 $2]=$0;next}$1 in a{print $0 ,a[$1 $2]}' file1 file2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your samples `3143137113` is not present in Input_file1 but still your shown output shows it as `31431,37113` please elaborate more that how it has come?

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Value 3143137113 is not present in file1.. The purpose is to check if values in file1 are in file2 then, replace the columns 2 and 3 in file2 using values of columns 4 and 5 from file1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{tmp=$0;sub($1 FS,"",tmp);a[$2 $3]=tmp;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF;next} {$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5);} 1' OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,2334362.30,100
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37219,319837.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,2334363.30,100
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
31433,36687,313187.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36723,313637.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36769,777775.60,2334361.90,100
31433,36825,314912.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36853,333322.00,2334362.80,102
```

Above assumes `$1` of `file` does not include regex characters, so to be accurate and safe, better use this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{$1="";a[$2 $3]=substr($0,2);next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF;next} {$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5);} 1' OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

However this one assumes the `FS` of `file1` is 1 character only.

And that leads to another change/efficiency improvement:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2 $3]=substr($0,length($1 FS)+1);next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF;next} {$1=substr($1,1,5) OFS substr($1,6,5);} 1' OFS=, file1 FS=' ' file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$2 $3]=$2 OFS $3
  b[$2 $3]=$4;c[$2 $3]=$5
  next
}
($1 in a){
  $2=b[$1]
  $3=c[$1];$1=a[$1]
  print
  next
}
{
  $1=$1
  sub(/^...../,"&,",$1)
  print
}
' FS=","   file1  FS=" " file2
```

Output will be as follows.

```
31431,37113,318512.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37131,999991.70,2334362.30,100
31431,37201,319612.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37219,319837.50,2334387.50,100
31431,37471,111113.20,2334363.30,100
31431,37491,323237.50,2334387.50,100
31433,36687,313187.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36723,313637.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36769,777775.60,2334361.90,100
31433,36825,314912.50,2334412.50,100
31433,36853,333322.00,2334362.80,102
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I tried both, but no one produce the desired output file.. many thanks for your help

Comment: per example this value 999991.70,2334362.30 not appears in output file.

Comment: @OXXO, please check my updated solutions and let me know ?

Comment: Ravider, code2 works, code1 does not generate the output desired.. Considering that you want to divide 1st field of Input_file2 in case Input_file1 and Input_file2 "is NOT having any match for a specific line then try following". The purpose is to replace lines who match..

Comment: @OXXO, code-1 too working fine for me, kindly check it once more and let me know then? It is giving expected output only thing it don't divide 1st field with comma. Let me know?

Comment: Ravinder, 31431,37131,,2334387.50,100 one values is missed in the output of fist code.

Comment: @OXXO, please see my edit where I added output which I am getting for 1st code and looks same like 2nd code(in terms of values I meant), let me know?